# Starting over with Flamenco in my Soul

Tags: flamenco

I started learning Flamenco with a teacher my age 56 years ago (I was 16).I thought I would play Classical, but found that it was too tedious, with little gratification. So Flamenco was more interesting and seemed more doable as a beginner to produce sound that had some feeing, and musicality.Dozens of cd's and numerous concerts later...

I do not read music, and played by chord progressions as I remember(I played clarinet in Jr High, forgot the rest). I had an old Harmony guitar from 1962. To upgrade, I bought a Cedar top Rosewood sides and back Ramirez guitar, thinking to start over with classical, but I realize I really remember loving the ease with which something could be learned and played to at least sound like guitar playing (not to denigrate practicing basics). I also have seen some of the greatest Flamenco guitarists play, and have dozens of guitar cd's with probably 25 being a Flamenco, Manitas de Plata, Montoya, Pepe Romero, and assorted others,especially Sabicas.

So with Flamenco in my soul and rust in my hands,I would like to find material to start over again with Flamenco simple. Basic guitar, like Position hands, posture, etc.,I need recommendations,books? Help!

Comment: Did you explore YouTube? I found many channels with videos teaching various techniques that I enjoy practicing. With your previous experience with flamenco, you will be able to recognize (better than me) which of these are more authentic. And then, perhaps you can let me know :)

Answer (score 2):

You want to start with Juan Martin's solos flamencos (MelBay); there are two volumes I think but the first one has simple falsettas and compas so you can start from scratch and play something you'll like in many different styles. There are CDs and DVDs with the method.